# Choose an alternative route in Mapbox iOS SDK

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm creating an app using Mapbox iOS SDK and I want to give an opportunity to choose between alternative routes, while user is in walking mode. So, the result should look like this:
[image]

Is it possible:

1) to show alternative routes in Mapbox iOS SDK?

2) to choose between them with tapping on polyline?

Comment: you can get alternative routes by setting "requestsAlternateRoutes" to "true" of your "MBDirectionsRequest" object.

Comment: Great! Can you help one again and tell how to show them on the map?

Comment: how are you drawing default path?...are you not getting alternate paths in same format?...

Comment: No. It just returns true.